# Inheritance and generic classes

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I recently did some work on adjusting the Dapper to my needs and it works quite good but I noticed I have certain code that repeates and I want to minify that as much as possible. Current way this works is:

I have a base DAL class that does some basic operation such as Save, Delete, Get, etc. Along with that it has a property named IsNew that...well...you've guessed determines if it's new or existing entity.

```
public class DalBase
{
   public bool IsNew
   {
      get;
      private set;
   }

   public static T New<T>()
   {
      // removed for clarity
   }

   public void Get<T>(params object[] parameters)
   {
      // removed for clarity
   }    

   public void Save()
   {
      // removed for clarity
   }

   public void Delete()
   {
      // removed for clarity
   }
}
```

If I want to define my entity, lets say person, I would do it this way:

```
public partial class Person
{
    private PersonDal m_dal;

    public bool IsNew
    {
        get
        {
            return m_dal.IsNew;
        }
    }

    public int? PersonID
    {
        get
        {
            return m_dal.PersonID;
        }
    }

    public string PersonName
    {
        get
        {
            return m_dal.PersonName;
        }
        set
        {
            m_dal.PersonName = value;
        }
    }

    public string PersonSurname
    {
        get
        {
            return m_dal.PersonSurname;
        }
        set
        {
            m_dal.PersonSurname = value;
        }
    }

    public DateTime? PersonDateOfBirth
    {
        get
        {
            return m_dal.PersonDateOfBirth;
        }
        set
        {
            m_dal.PersonDateOfBirth = value;
        }
    }

    private Person()
    {
        m_dal = DalBase.New<PersonDal>();
    }

    public static Person New()
    {
        return new Person();
    }

    public static Person Get(int PersonID)
    {
        var personDal = DalBase.Get<PersonDal>(PersonID);

        if (personDal == null)
            return null;

        var person = new Person();
        person.m_dal = personDal;
        return person;
    }

    private class PersonDal : DalBase
    {
        public int? PersonID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string PersonName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string PersonSurname
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public DateTime? PersonDateOfBirth
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        private PersonDal()
        {
            IsNew = true;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see my DAL is contained inside the Entity class. This way I can do all sorts of things like mappings, preliminary checks before update or insert, etc. But, this is not why I copy pasted this code here :)

What I want to do is somehow eliminate IsNew from the entity because it will repeate on every entity definition and it seems a bit redundant AND more because I might be thinking of adding some columns that are common for all tables such as DateOfEdit, UserEdit, etc... As you can see it would be very handy to add it in one place and than inherit it and just keep specific columns in each entity definition.

What I tried doing by now is using generics like this:

```
public class EntityBase<T> where T : DalBase
{
    protected T m_dal;

    public bool IsNew
    {
        get
        {
            return m_dal.IsNew;
        }
    }
}
```

This would allow me to inherit base entity with specific Dal class so I can have my person entity defined as such:

```
public partial class Person : EntityBase<PersonDal>
```

The problem with this approach is that the PersonDal is private class of Person entity and as such has less accessibility than the entity itself and if I just define it as public - well it beats the whole purpose since the DAL is used only by the entity that is concerned with it!

Is there any other way that we could achieve this?

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating things... How about having a datalayer project and using `internal` for things that you dont want outside?

Comment: Internal doesn't cut it since it would still be available from the same file. DAL shouldn't be accessible from anywhere else than from the entity class.

Comment: But it looks like you still plan to create it outside the entity class in `DalBase.New<T>()`. Also, who is stopping a malicious coder from creating a copy of `PersonDal` wherever he wants? Using nested classes should be enough of a hint to not use the class randomly, even when it is internal accessible. This whole idea is pretty flawed.

Comment: I do not plan to create it outside entity class. Generic is there so the specific Dal can be instantiated. In the example I have Person with private class named PersonDal which inherits DalBase and the method New<T> is used so we can instantiate PersonDal inside Person entity.

Answer (score 1):

DAL has nothing to do with the entities. You mix the concepts here. Use DAL as an individual class, not as a member field/variable of your entity classes and pass the entity types to DAL. 
If you have to have the DAL in your entities, use DI and pass the DAL instance in the constructor.

Or if you want to use your original approach, create a simple EF project with two entity types and check how it works.

Comment: The way things are set up now DAL has everything to do with the entity. Since the DAL is used to insert, update, delete or fetch SINGLE row. Because of this there is no use in having it as a separate class since no one else will use it except the entity itself.

Comment: DAL does not need to know the objects - just need to persist into the DB. Inheritance is the only usable way here, like EF or nhibernate. 
http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/nh-quickstart.html

having a private dal entity in every instance is at least questionable from concurrency aspects.

Comment: I know that theory says that DAL has to know the instances, but 
1. in practice the DAL should know the tables in the DB and map the instance properties to the table - if it is reflection or some EF/nhibernate like tricks, does not matters, expect the speed.
2. if you call paramterized SPs, DAL needs to know even less - copy SP param values with reflection and instantiate result entites with reflection also, thats all.

Comment: I do not see how this is questionable from concurrency aspects.

Comment: 10 Person instances with 10 parallel dals means 10 inserts at the same time with 10 open concurrent connections.

Comment: Well if you want to do it at the same time than you will have concurrent connections. Thats what you get when you want to do anything at the same time.

Comment: Still don't get it mate. Deadlocks?! Where?! If you have concurrent calls to Save on 10 different DALs then you will open 10 separate connections not use one connection. I can read on deadlocks but I don't think it will benefit the initial question or this discussion we are having.

Comment: i quit, forget it. you dont wanna understand, you wont. bye.

Comment: If you actually took time to read the code I posted you would see the way the thing is set up. Instead you started providing your way of looking at the way DALs and Entities should coexist and cooperate which is waaaaaay of the question asked in the first place. If you look at the tags of the question everything will be clear. So please for your future attempts to help people when they ask for help, instead of advising them on something completely irrelevant to the question, try to help them. This way you are just ruining the question! Bye!

Comment: Just check the comments from grek40, they are in sync with my comments.